# Odd number of elements in hash assignment error

Tags: perl

I was learning Perl Objects. I wrote a simple constructor in a module file **create_schedules.pm**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
package create_schedules;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %params = @_;
    my $self=bless{
        _para1=>$params{'mypara1'},
        _para2=>$params{'mypara2'}
        },$class;
    return $self;
}
1;
```

and I am creating an object in a main file **main.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use lib::my_module;

sub _start(){
    print "Main Function Started\n";
    create_schedules::new( 
        'mypara1' => 'This is mypara1', 
        'mypara2' => 'This is mypara2',
        );
}
_start();
```

As soon as I run main.pl, I got following error:

```
Main Function Started
 Odd number of elements in hash assignment at lib/create_schedules.pm line 9 (#1)
 (W misc) You specified an odd number of elements to initialize a hash,
 which is odd, because hashes come in key/value pairs.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call with:

```
create_schedules->new
#   note     ___^^
```

An old way to call was:

```
new create_schedules(...);
```

Why your code is wrong:

In the new method you're doing `my $class = shift;`,  after that, `@_` will contain only 3 elements:

1. 'This is mypara1',
2. 'mypara2',
3. 'This is mypara2',

Then the instruction `my %params = @_;` will cause the warning about odd number of elements.

Comment: It runs properly now. Why create_schedules::new is incorrect.

Comment: @ritesh_NITW: because you aren't giving the packages to the method.

Answer (score 5):

You used the function directly, not as an object:

```
create_schedules::new
               #^^-- this
```

Instead of

```
create_schedules->new
```

When you do that, this line:

```
my $class = shift;
```

Does not contain the object, but the first element of your hash assignment. And if you remove one element, the list is now a number of elements that is odd.

Although I do note that your package names are not the same. You are using `create_schedules` in the main, and `my_module` in the module.